# How to host images when using HTTP/2

Tags: http2

We are **migrating** our page **to HTTP/2**.

When using HTTP/1 there was a limitation of 2 concurrent connections per host. Usually, a technique called [sharding](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/getting-ready-for-http2/#splitting-resources-between-hosts-sharding) was used to work around that. 
So content was delivered from www.example.com and the images from img.example.com. 
Also, you wouldn't send all the cookies for www.example.com to the image domain, which also saves bandwidth (see [What is a cookie free domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/78227/what-is-a-cookie-free-domain)).

Things have changed with HTTP/2; what is the best way to serve images using HTTP/2?

- same domain?
- different domain?

Comment: Your question is simply too broad. The HTTP protocol version says very little about how you want to do your image serving,

Comment: when serving images, a few bytes of cookies will be utterly insignificant

Comment: I've not met a hoster with a <20 connection limit per peer since 1999. You should consider switching your hoster or just removing that limit.

Comment: by the way, I think one of the major advantages of HTTP/2 is compressed headers and connection reuse – your cookies won't be transmitted twice by your browser, usually.

Comment: iirc the two connection limit was removed in http/1.1

Answer (score 1):

Short:

No sharding is required, HTTP/2 web servers usually have a liberal connection limit.

As with HTTP/1.1, keep the files as small as possible, HTTP/2 still is bound  by the same bandwidth physical constraints.

Multi-plexing is really a plus for concurrent image loading. There are a few demos out there, you can Google them. I can point you to the one that I did:

https://demo1.shimmercat.com/10/